# Expected Value of this function

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms, permutations

Let’s consider a random permutation p1, p2, …, pN of numbers 1, 2, …, N and Function F is calculated as F=(X[2]+…+X[N-1])^K, where

```
X[i]=1 if p[i-1] < p[i] > p[i+1] OR p[i-1] > p[i] < p[i+1] 

X[i]=0 Otherwise
```

What is the expected value of F?

EXAMPLE : If K=1 and N=1000 then answer for this will be 1996/3 here.

Comment: Hint: linearity of expectations.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Could u please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the $K$. Linearity alone will only work for $K=1$.

Comment: @Henry oh yeah ..right

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- What is the probability that p_i is the lowest of $p_{i-1},p_i,p_{i+1}$?
- What is the probability that p_i is the highest of $p_{i-1},p_i,p_{i+1}$?
- What is the probability that p_i is the highest or lowest of $p_{i-1},p_i,p_{i+1}$?
- What is the probability that X_i=1?
- What is the expectation of X_i?
- How many $i$s are there
- What is the expectation of $\sum_i X_i$?

It gets harder for $K \gt 1$

Comment: Can you explain with an example... k can go upto 5.

Comment: What to do for k>1